# How to make a guided tour for the website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve something similar to this page https://www.quantopian.com/algorithms. If you click on the `Guided Tour` button on the right top corner, you will see what I mean. Can anyone point me to some tutorial or ideas how to implement this?

To be specific in case the site is down. I want some kind of step by step pop up message box that guides the first-time user to get familiar with the app. While the popup is shown, the rest of the app should be disabled, and the only button the user can click on is the next step or close button on the message box.

**UPDATE:**
There seem to be way more javascript libraries than I expected. This one from Linkedin seems to be well maintained on github: https://github.com/LinkedInAttic/hopscotch.

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."* SO doesn't allow questions that rely solely on off-site content, because off-site content rots (quickly), and separately people shouldn't have to go off-site to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the explanation. I just edited my post. Will this conform to the the guidance?

Comment: @zsljulius: That's the kind of thing, nice one. But it's not just in case that site is down. The focus of the question should be your explanation, then "(for example, [this site](http://example.com) does this)."

Comment: [Sideshow](http://fortesinformatica.github.io/Sideshow) is a modern and powerful library for creating interactive tours for web applications and sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for it: May even be made with this on your demo example site.

clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/

Comment: yea, this one looks very similar to the one they use too.Thanks

Comment: No probs hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like what you are looking for - [Tourist](https://github.com/easelinc/tourist)

Comment: I think this is actually the library they use! Thanks!